# Condition in "if" ignored in "for" loop

Tags: c++, if-statement

For below code, when input is:

> first input = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> second input = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

it will produce output of:

> first output = 0
>
> second output = 1

instead of taking each input quartile it take its first element, and the problem is (after testing and such), it follow with the problem in code

```
for (vector<int>::size_type counter = 0; (quartiles < quadro) && (counter < numstore.size()); ++counter)
{
    if (counter == (quartiles/quadro * numstore.size()))
    {
        quaele.push_back(numstore[counter]);
        if ((quartiles == 2) && (numstore.size() / 2 == 0))
            quaele[quartiles-1] = (numstore[counter]+numstore[counter-1]) / 2;
        ++quartiles;
    }
    // test
    cout << quartiles;
}
```

where the conditional in "if function" doesn't work, I mean on first loop, `counter == 0`, how can `0 == 1(quartiles)/4(quadro) * 10(numstore.size()`??

Comment: you are doing int operations, so `1/4 == 0`

Comment: what's wrong in my code of course? 

"how can 0 == 1(quartiles)/4(quadro) * 10(numstore.size()??"

Comment: omg, thnx vulkanino, you should put this on answer part thought...

Comment: By `quartiles/quadro * numstore.size()` which condition do you expect ? `(quartiles/quadro) * numstore.size()` or `quartiles / (quadro * numstore.size())` ? I believe the problem is in your condition. Put braces around and check.

Comment: @iammilind , well, if u learn how to search quartile in math, you should know that (1/4) * total element = first quartile.

Comment: So this _entire_ question could have been narrowed down to a one-line testcase -- the conditional -- and then you'd had been able to see quite simply from existing questions what the problem is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit First, I don't know what's wrong, second what the probability that my code is wrong on other part? I don't know. that's why I post the full code, it's not 50K lines by the way!

Comment: @Vastor: That's why you should perform _reduction_, breaking down your code into component _testcases_ to narrow down the issue. It's the first step in debugging.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit k, I hope not getting critique for giving lack of info... ;))

Comment: @Vastor: A minimal, complete testcase is 100% of info required to solve the problem, by definition, because you narrowed down the problem to that small area :) It seems like you did already do that in your head, so I'd have just abstracted everything else away leaving this: http://ideone.com/nsq8k, then asked "how is this printing `true`?!"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8671/discussion-between-vastor-and-lightness-races-in-orbit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `quartiles` and `quadro` are both integers and the first is always less than the second (because that's what the `for` statement says), the expression:

```
quartiles / quadro * numstore.size()
```

will *always* be equal to zero, because `quartiles / quadro` is calculated first. Hence, the `if` statement will only ever be true the first time through the loop.

You may be able to get around this by re-arranging the calculation:

```
quartiles * numstore.size() / quadro
```

Comment: Better yet would be to add parentheses, so that evaluation is completely clear

Comment: Obviously that does not go for original poster :P

Answer (score 2):

That's how integer arithmetic works. `1/4` is truncated to zero.

You can get the correct result (rounded down to the nearest integer) by multiplying first:

```
(quartiles * numstore.size()) / quadro
```

I've used parentheses to make the evaluation order clear - you could leave them out if you prefer.

Note that, for large values, you'll need to be careful that the multiplication doesn't overflow - perhaps by converting to a wider type, or to floating point, or by carefully multiplying and dividing by smaller factors. That is probably not an issue in this case.

Comment: wow, it's kind of shame to forgot the basic rule in programming of integer, I think I want to cry in the corner... D:

Comment: while it is completely true, it is also completely weird (that it works this way)!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mean, changing the order of the operands completely changes the result, it is not immediate when reading the code and very much error prone. In trivial arithmetics `1/4*10 = 1*10/4`

Comment: @vulkanino: Indeed. It's weird if you expect variables to behave like real numbers; not so weird if you understand that they must have a finite representation.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `quartiles/quadro * numstore.size()` will be 0 for the case where quartiles = 1 and quadro = 4. This is because 1/4 is rounded downwards to 0.

Maybe this is what you mean: `(quartiles * numstore.size()) / quadro`

Comment: Noted parentheses are still failing and I guess the result is not what is expected. (quartiles * numstore.size())) / quadro should do fine.

Answer (score 0):

quartiles/quadro is equal to 0.25 and because quartiles is type int quartiles/quadro == 0

Comment: so wrong, ++counter happen at the end of loop not on start...

you right about int thought..

Comment: @Vastor totaly missed this :)

Answer (score 0):

In `C++` when you divide two integer, you get integer division. Moreover, `*` and `/` have the same precedence, so the parser interprets it as `(quartiles / quadro) * numstore.size()`.  And `(1 / 4)` is equal to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the division operator can be thought of as **two different operators**: one that works on integer operands, and one that works on floating point operands. If the operands are of a floating point type, the division operator will return a floating point value.

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-programming/eight-c-programming-mistakes-the-compiler-wont-catch/

Try:

```
float result = quartiles/quadro * numstore.size();
```

edit: correcting thanks to the comments.

```
float result = quartiles/(float)quadro * numstore.size();
```

It is enough to convert one of the operands to a floating point number.

Comment: No. `quartiles` and `quadro` are both integers, so you're still performing integer division before converting and assigning the result, `0`, to a `float`.

Comment: Actually, that won't work because the calculation will still be done as integer then converted to float in the assignment - in other words, it will simply be the float equivalent of the wrong value.